# Проблема с определением координат указателя мыши в imgui

Tags: c++, gui

Рассматривал стандартный [пример](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/tree/master/examples/example_sdl_opengl3) `imgui` для `sdl` и `opengl3` и обнаружил такую вещь: координаты указателя мыши, по видимому, неверно определеяются, из-за чего чтобы, к примеру, кликнуть мышкой по кнопке, нужно наводить не левый верхний угол, а нижний правый угол указателя... С чем вообще может быть такое связано?

Answer (score -1):

Координаты мыши определяются верно, т.к. используются системные вызовы. Если бы они определялись неверно, то в ОС было бы тоже неверно. Так что либо конкретно пример содержит баги, либо вы что-то неправильно интерпретируете. 
Попробуйте вызвать `ImGui::ShowDemoWindow()`, там есть куча примеров, включая координаты мыши. Если там не работает, то пишите пишите в багтрекер.

Comment: Что значит: "используются системные вызовы"? На это посмотрите сначала: https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/blob/master/examples/imgui_impl_sdl.cpp - 230 строчка. С проблемой я, кстати, разобрался.